# Can I apply for masters program on Polymer Science after having completed my masters of Pharmacy..

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, international-students, science

I completed my master in 2012 with a specialization in Pharmacognosy. After completing my graduation, I joined a company as a Pharmacist due to unavailability of job related to my area. Currently I am working as a asst prof in a reputed organization. Few months after joining i realized the narrow opportunities of Pharmacognosy. Later I started to search articles on natural polymers, that lead to go for a second masters program on polymer science. 
Please suggest me am I in the right path. And how do I mention this on my application and statement of purpose/motivation letter. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look for other questions about switching fields -- you'll find some helpful general advice.